# IBM IHS with proxypass the httpserver url redirects with application port and fails to load page

Tags: ibmhttpserver

I am using IBM IHS 8.5.5.17 version with proxypass settings. IHS is on port 80 and application server on 21010. When i try the url http://httpserverHost/myApp, it redirects to http://httpserverHost:21010/myApp and fails to load the page as 21010 is of application port.

I have used following configurations in IHS

`ProxyPreserveHost On`
`ProxyPass /myApp balancer://cluster/myApp/`
`<Proxy balancer://cluster>`
`BalancerMember http://hostname1:21010 route=1 loadfactor=1`
`BalancerMember http://hostname2:21010 route=2 loadfactor=1`
`</Proxy>`

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Gopal

Comment: Is the application running on WAS? You are meant to use the WAS WebServer Plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Every basic mod_proxy config uses `ProxyPassReverse` to fixup redirects from the backend.  Note that if you use `ProxyPreserveHost` the 2nd argument needs to match httpserverHost:21010 not hostname1/hostname2.

Comment: The issue is browser  url is  changing to application port 21010 instead of retaining  httpserver port.

Comment: Right, and ProxyPassReverse is the typical way to fix this kind of redirect.